# How to solve $\cos^2x - \sin^2x -1 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The answers from the back of the book says the answers are $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$. I thought that you can use the double angle formula in this problem, but it doesn't seem right?

Comment: I did, and changed the problem to cos2x = 1, and then divided by 2 (not exactly sure if that's possible), to get cosx = 1/2. The answers I got was different from the book.

Comment: it is easy to check  books' answers

Comment: Alternatively, note 

that if $$\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)$$ we must have $\sin^2(x) = 0$ so that $x \in \{n\pi : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: Answers below and comment above are all correct. But I'd like to warn you: no, it's **not** possible to "divide" by $2$ the way you did. The reason is that $\cos(2x)\neq2\cos(x)$, as these are two very different things.

Answer (score 5):

As you suggest, since $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$, this is equivalent to the equation $\cos 2x = 1$, which has solutions when $2x$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so the solutions are
$$x = \dots, -2\pi, -\pi, 0, \pi, 2\pi, \dots$$
So the book has the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)$,
So $\cos(2x) = 1$ has solutions of the form $2x = 2k\pi$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$
That is $x = k\pi$ where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos^2x-\sin^2x-1=0$$

Recall the idenity

$$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$

$$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$$

$$\cos^2x-(1-\cos^2x)=1$$

$$2\cos^2x=2$$

$$\cos^2x=1$$

You may proceed with these,

Also notice that

$$\cos^2x-1=\sin^2x$$

$$\sin^2x=0$$